# Convert string to float without Decimal Point and Exponential values

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a scenario where I receive Phone Numbers and I have to save those numbers to database.

The Phone Number column in DB is of type `float`.
But I am receiving phone numbers as string.

They may contain spaces or other characters.

I have written a code to remove characters and concert the resulting string to float. But I am getting output with exponential values, which in-turn getting modified in database.

I have a following code

```
string phone1="68 8845 62529";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex digitsOnly = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[^\d]");
float f = float.Parse(digitsOnly.Replace(phone1, string.Empty), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```

My Input is  `"68 8845 62529"`

I am getting the output as `6.888456E+9`

Value getting stored in database `68884560512`

I want the output as `float f= 68884562529`

Final datatype has to be float.

Please help.

Comment: "The Phone Number column in DB is of type float" - that sounds like a bad idea to start with. Are you able to change that?

Comment: No. That is the main problem

Comment: So which database is this, and what's the *exact* field type? Bear in mind that a C# `float` value only has 7-9 digits of precision - you're trying to represent a value with 11 digits, so you're *bound* to lose information.

Comment: Right, so a field type of just `float` is closer to `double` in C#, which has 15-16 digits of precision.

Comment: Phone numbers aren't floats. They are strings that can have digits and some special characters like `+`, `#` and `*`` that aren't related to formatting. Trying to treat them as floats is a very, *very* bad idea

Comment: Fix your database bug. There's no point in trying to mangle a phone number so that it fits a float. International numbers or long-distance codes are enough to break whatever you attempt

Answer (score 6):

The first problem is that choosing a floating point numeric type to represent a phone number is a *terrible* idea, which is likely to cause you problems all over the place. I would urge you to work out just how much effort it would take to change this bad decision. If you really, really can't change that though, you can at least improve on what you've got.

If you're using the [SQL Server `float` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173773.aspx), without specifying a precision, that's probably equivalent to using `double`. So use `double.Parse` instead of `float.Parse`, and provide the value to the database as a `double`. Ignore any textual representation you may see along the way - you're just trying to preserve the numeric value of the `double`. The problem you're currently facing is that you're using the `float` type, which only has 7-9 digits of precision, but the value you're trying to parse has 11 digits.

You're *effectively* trying to store large integers. Using the `float` type gives you 53 bits of precision for those integers, so any integer less than 2<sup>53</sup> *should* be able to be stored precisely, and will hopefully not give you problems - but you'll need to make sure that when you inevitably want to turn it back into text, you do so without losing information. This should be okay for all numbers with only 14 digits or fewer.

As noted in comments, you're going to find it hard to understand numbers which differ based on whether they start with leading zeroes, which are clearly irrelevant in terms of a numeric value, but important in terms of a phone representation.

Comment: I don't think the OP can't *not* change the type. What happens with international numbers? Or long distance codes? Missing those `00` can convert a Russian mobile number to a Romanian one (or was it Bulgaria?)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: 14 digits gives quite a lot of leeway, although there's work required to understand that leading zeroes are important too... To be fair, we don't know the context here. (Maybe international numbers aren't required?) I have strongly urged them to change it in the first paragraph though.

Answer (score -1):

first convert to String and after converting remove '.' from string.
now u can store as a string as well as decimal by convert into decimal.

Comment: This ignores the point, which is to store the value as a `float` value in the database.